# How to style the actions on AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui

Currently, for some reason, the code below returns an AlertDialog with white action buttons 'YES' and 'NO'.
[this is the picture](https://imgur.com/a/z13XdSk).

I want to change the color of the buttons WITHOUT specifying it in AlertDialog widget itself. What I am looking for is some sort of parent theme configuration from which the AlertDialog inherits the colors I want.

Why do I want this?
I am using the Paystack Plugin and the cancel confirmation dialog is setup exactly like this. I can't change the plugin code itself.

What I have tried?
I have tried setting the `primaryColor` and `buttonTheme` properties of theme on the `MaterialApp`.

Thanks

```
showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (c) => AlertDialog(
                      content: Text('text'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        TextButton(
                            child: const Text('NO'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(
                                  false); // Pops the confirmation dialog but not the page.
                            }),
                        TextButton(
                            child: const Text('YES'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(
                                  true); // Returning true to _onWillPop will pop again.
                            })
                      ],
                    ));
```

I have checked other questions around this and folks suggested to either put custom action widgets of just style the Text Widgets. I can't do either because this widget is part of the Paystack Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart#L359) of `AlertDialog`, there is no additional `ThemeData` that is merged to the widgets given from the `actions` parameter, which means your requirement is **impossible**. The only way to customize the buttons globally is by specifying a custom `textButtonTheme` in the `ThemeData`.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    // ...
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.yellow),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.red),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  // ...
)
```

Comment: I accept this answer because it helped me find the answer. It is actually the 'foreground' property of the buttonStyle that changes the text colors. You could modify your. answer. 
Thanks for saving me!

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize you were asking for the text color. I've updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add buttonBarTheme inside your theme data:

```
 theme: ThemeData(
    // Define the button theme
    buttonBarTheme: ButtonBarThemeData(
      buttonTextTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
    ),
  ),
```

Note: You can also specify more properties.

Comment: it is still white bro

Answer (score 0):

This is AlertDialog.And also style the actions

```
Future<void> _showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) async {
   return showDialog<void>(
     context: context,
     builder: (BuildContext context) {
       return AlertDialog(
         title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
         content: SingleChildScrollView(
           child: ListBody(
             children: <Widget>[
               Text('This is an example AlertDialog.'),
             ],
           ),
         ),
         actions: <Widget>[
           TextButton(
             style: ButtonStyle(
               foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
             
             ),
             onPressed: () {
               Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
        
             },
             child: Text('Cancel'),
           ),
           TextButton(
             style: ButtonStyle(
               backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
   
             ),
             onPressed: () {
               Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the AlertDialog
              
             },
             child: Text('OK'),
           ),
         ],
       );
     },
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: You did not understand my question bro. I do not want to make any edit to the AlertDialog itself

Answer (score 0):

Use `showDialog` widget and also return `Container` inside builder, use decoration to design as per your expectation.

```
showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (c) => Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 10,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: const Text('NO'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop(
                            false,
                          ); // Pops the confirmation dialog but not the page.
                        },
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        child: const Text('YES'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop(
                            true,
                          ); // Returning true to _onWillPop will pop again.
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Comment: You did not understand. the question bro

Comment: oh, ok. 
You wanted to make changes to whole app without changing in the 'Text' widget.